# 4 input CMOS NOR gate simulation showing metastability

Tags: ltspice

I'm simulating a 4 input NOR gate in LTSPICE but with different inputs, i.e., the inputs going into the Pull-up network are different from the inputs going into the Pull-down network. The inputs are square waves arranged to form a Gray Code counter (so only one input changes at any given time). I expected the NOR gate to respond with either a 0 or 1 but it goes metastable most times.

Here's my NOR gate:
[image]

Here are the square pulse inputs in the schematic file I'm using in Gray Code format:
[image]

The inputs look like so:
[image]

Finally, this is my output for the 4 input NOR:
[image]

As you can see, the output is showing some metastability instead of landing on 0 or 1.

I'm not using any MOSFET models. Just the ideal NMOS4 and PMOS4 models. For now, both NMOS4 and PMOS4 have aspect ratio 1.8u/0.6u.

What could be causing this metastability?

Comment: I think you are misusing the term "metastability". The term really applies to digital storage elements (flop flops) that may not latch properly at the clocking time if their inputs are not stable and meeting setup and hold times.

Comment: I'm sorry. What I meant to say was the circuit is "unstable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The P-tree (pull-up network) needs to be driven the same as the N-tree (pull-down network). The circuit is a four input NOR, but you are driving it with 8 inputs. The result is that sometimes neither the P-tree nor N-tree are conducting and therefore the output is floating. Or, both the P-tree and the N-tree are conducting causing the output to be mid-level (and lots of current consumption).

The proper way to test a 4 input NOR is to use only 4 voltage sources and drive I0=I2, I1=I3, I4=I6, and I5=I7.

Answer (score 1):

> I expected the NOR gate to respond with either a 0 or 1 but it goes metastable most times.

Why would you expect a consistent result when you stimulate it in inconsistent ways?

If neither the pull-up nor the pull-down network is activated, the output will be left floating, and may bounce around based on whatever happened to be on the output rail previously.

If both the pull-up and pull-down networks are activated, the output will be pulled to roughly mid-rail (and the circuit will consume an excessive amount of power).

(As an aside: Neither of these are technically "metastable". That's only possible in a recurrent circuit, like a latch.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the current to see if its real, if it shows values that are too high, then insert passive resistance and or inductance (that would exist physically) at the appropriate points in the circuit.

One problem with spice is it behaves ideally, switched inductors can reach mega volts, rise times that are in the fs and currents that can be mega amps. As soon as you start throwing in real world resistance inductance or capacitance, the circuit behaves more like the real world.